# edge connectivity graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, matrix

I need help with a pseudocode for an algorithm that solves the 3-edge connectivity problem:
input: a graph G in adjacency matrix format

output: true if, for every pair of vertices v,w elements of G, there exists a path from v to w of length at most 3

Any Ideas? This is what I have so far.

```
const int WIDTH = 10;
const HIGHT =10;
Int arrayMatrix [WIDTH] [HIGHT];

for (int i =0; i< WIDTH; i++)
{
for (int j =0; j<HIGHT; j++)
{
int countEdges =0;
countEdges = countEdges +arrayMatrix [i];
}
if countEdges<=3
cout << "True for 3-edge connectivity problem" << endl;
else 
cout <<"Not found" << enld;
```

Comment: Title says edge connectivity, but the "output" bit is about diameter. Which one do you want?

Comment: 3-edge connectivity problem, nothing about diameter. just 3 edges at most

Comment: My point was that: "true if, for every pair of vertices v,w elements of G, there exists a path from v to w of length at most 3" <- is **not** edge-connectivity!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a technique similar to the Warshall-Floyd algorithm, to compute G^3, but where for matrix multiplication you have the following operation

(X * Y)ij = OR [all k] (Xik AND Ykj).

now compute (G*G)*G (with your input adjacency matrix).

Return true if the result matrix contains only 'true' elements.

Comment: (G^k)ij = true IFF there is a length k or less path from vertex i to vertex j in G.